# Create a trigger after insert with a condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger to insert into another table the ID row if a certain conditions are verified.

**SWAB_TEST**

```
id_swab
id_user 
result
```

**NO_INFECTED**

```
id_user
```

For example i want to insert into NO_INFECTED table the ID of the user who swab test is negative

**SWAB_TEST**

```
id_swab : Test1
id_user : 1
result  : negative
```

**NO_INFECTED**

```
id_user: 1
```

I created this trigger but I don't know how to insert the condition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigg 
AFTER INSERT ON swab_test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO no_infected (id_user)
 VALUES(:new.id_user);
END;
```

Comment: Just to comment on coding style, you don't have to code in block caps (although, sadly, a lot of people do). Also, a 1 character indent seems to me pessimistic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add an `IF` condition with `:new.result = 'negative'` control :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigg 
AFTER INSERT ON swab_test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :new.result = 'negative' THEN
 INSERT INTO no_infected (id_user)
 VALUES (:new.id_user);
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, can I ask why  [ :new.result = 'negative' ] and not [ :old.result = 'negative'] ?

Comment: Hi @Gwynbleidd, for an insert trigger `:old` contains no value. Isn't that logical :) ?

Comment: Yes... sorry for my useless question but i'm studying now plsql, thanks again! :)

Comment: No, no, nevermind, even useful I think, you're welcome @Gwynbleidd .